# Prove with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ that $\lim_ {x\to 0} |x|=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$  that  $\lim_{x\to 0} |x|=0$. I just have to find the $\delta$ that works with $\left||x| -0\right|< \epsilon$. Following the absolute value definition I found that when $x>0$, then $\epsilon=\delta$. But I´m stuck when $x<0$, what should I do in that case?.

Comment: Why do you think this is a different case?

Comment: Note that $\left| |x|-0\right|=\left| \ |x| \ \right|=|x|$

Comment: @MattSamuel  Cause when I do it I get |-x|< $\epsilon$ and I don´t know how to put it to the get |x| so I can compare it with $\delta$

Comment: Note that $|-x|=|x|$.

Answer (score 2):

Put aside the definition of absolute value for a moment and focus on the definition of a limit. Can you convince yourself that what you want is to find a $\delta$ such that if $|x|<\delta$, then $|x|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Well I think so, as far as I understand that´s the way it should be proved or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @Raquelnb it seems that what you are doing is correct and if that works for you go ahead with it. This answer suggests a method that may be a bit shorter.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ is that $$\forall \epsilon \gt 0\ \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } 0\lt|x-a|\lt \delta \implies |f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon$$

In this case

$$||x|-0|=|x|=|x-0|$$
So just choose $\delta = \epsilon$, then $|x-0|\lt \delta \implies ||x|-0|\lt \epsilon$ and you're done.